# Im trying to make a jukebox with I2S and ESP32 but when I try to play music from a folder instead of a specific song it doesn't work

Tags: audio, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, i2s

Im trying to make a jukebox with an esp32 using I2S. When the button is pressed the music should play. I can already get 1 song playing but once I try to make songs play from a folder it doesnt seem to work for me. The code below is the working code does anyone know how I can change this code so it could play a folder instead of just 1 song?

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Audio.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "FS.h"

#define SD_CS          5
#define SPI_SCK        18
#define SPI_MOSI       23    // SD Card
#define SPI_MISO       19
#define BUTTON_PIN     2

#define I2S_DOUT       25
#define I2S_BCLK       27    // I2S
#define I2S_LRC        26

bool playing = false;
bool lastButtonState = false;
bool buttonPressed = false;

Audio audio;

void setup() {
    pinMode(SD_CS, OUTPUT);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(SD_CS, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);
    delay(500);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
        Serial.println("Error talking to SD card!");
        while (true);  // end program
    }
    audio.setPinout(I2S_BCLK, I2S_LRC, I2S_DOUT);
    audio.setVolume(14); // 0...21
    // audio.connecttoFS(SD, "/Muziek1/SnapInsta.io - K3 - De 3 Biggetjes (128 kbps).mp3");
    audio.connecttoFS(SD, "/Muziek1 ");
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // Configure button pin as input with pull-up resistor
}

//buttonState 1 is False
//butonState 2 is True

void loop() {
    int buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
    Serial.println(lastButtonState);
    if (buttonState != lastButtonState){
        if (lastButtonState) //Checks if the lastButtonState is True and if so it changes the playing boolean. Regardless of the outcame lastButtonState will be changed.
          playing = !playing;
        lastButtonState = buttonState;
    }
    if (playing)   //If playing is True audio.loop
      audio.loop();
    
    delay(10);  // small delay to debounce the button
}
```

I tried combining the code below with mine but it doesnt really work.If I click the button it doesnt work.

```
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"

void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * dirname, uint8_t levels){
  Serial.printf("Listing directory: %s\n", dirname);

  File root = fs.open(dirname);
  if(!root){
    Serial.println("Failed to open directory");
    return;
  }
  if(!root.isDirectory()){
    Serial.println("Not a directory");
    return;
  }

  File file = root.openNextFile();
  while(file){
    if(file.isDirectory()){
      Serial.print("  DIR : ");
      Serial.println(file.name());
      if(levels){
        listDir(fs, file.name(), levels -1);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.print("  FILE: ");
      Serial.print(file.name());
      Serial.print("  SIZE: ");
      Serial.println(file.size());
    }
    file = root.openNextFile();
  }
}

void createDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Creating Dir: %s\n", path);
  if(fs.mkdir(path)){
    Serial.println("Dir created");
  } else {
    Serial.println("mkdir failed");
  }
}

void removeDir(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Removing Dir: %s\n", path);
  if(fs.rmdir(path)){
    Serial.println("Dir removed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("rmdir failed");
  }
}

void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Read from file: ");
  while(file.available()){
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }
  file.close();
}

void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message){
  Serial.printf("Writing file: %s\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }
  if(file.print(message)){
    Serial.println("File written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Write failed");
  }
  file.close();
}

void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message){
  Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
    return;
  }
  if(file.print(message)){
      Serial.println("Message appended");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Append failed");
  }
  file.close();
}

void renameFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path1, const char * path2){
  Serial.printf("Renaming file %s to %s\n", path1, path2);
  if (fs.rename(path1, path2)) {
    Serial.println("File renamed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Rename failed");
  }
}

void deleteFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  Serial.printf("Deleting file: %s\n", path);
  if(fs.remove(path)){
    Serial.println("File deleted");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Delete failed");
  }
}

void testFileIO(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
  File file = fs.open(path);
  static uint8_t buf[512];
  size_t len = 0;
  uint32_t start = millis();
  uint32_t end = start;
  if(file){
    len = file.size();
    size_t flen = len;
    start = millis();
    while(len){
      size_t toRead = len;
      if(toRead > 512){
        toRead = 512;
      }
      file.read(buf, toRead);
      len -= toRead;
    }
    end = millis() - start;
    Serial.printf("%u bytes read for %u ms\n", flen, end);
    file.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
  }


  file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }

  size_t i;
  start = millis();
  for(i=0; i<2048; i++){
    file.write(buf, 512);
  }
  end = millis() - start;
  Serial.printf("%u bytes written for %u ms\n", 2048 * 512, end);
  file.close();
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if(!SD.begin(5)){
    Serial.println("Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint8_t cardType = SD.cardType();

  if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
    Serial.println("No SD card attached");
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("SD Card Type: ");
  if(cardType == CARD_MMC){
    Serial.println("MMC");
  } else if(cardType == CARD_SD){
    Serial.println("SDSC");
  } else if(cardType == CARD_SDHC){
    Serial.println("SDHC");
  } else {
    Serial.println("UNKNOWN");
  }

  uint64_t cardSize = SD.cardSize() / (1024 * 1024);
  Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);

  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  createDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 0);
  removeDir(SD, "/mydir");
  listDir(SD, "/", 2);
  writeFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "Hello ");
  appendFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "World!\n");
  readFile(SD, "/hello.txt");
  deleteFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  renameFile(SD, "/hello.txt", "/foo.txt");
  readFile(SD, "/foo.txt");
  testFileIO(SD, "/test.txt");
  Serial.printf("Total space: %lluMB\n", SD.totalBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
  Serial.printf("Used space: %lluMB\n", SD.usedBytes() / (1024 * 1024));
}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: `audio.connecttoFS(SD, String("/Muziek1/") + file.name());`?

Comment: `audio.connecttoFS(SD, "/Muziek1 ");` – is the space in the directory name intended?

Comment: It wasn't. I fixed that but it didn't fix the issue